# Beamer figure grows larger when pointing on it

Tags: beamer, graphics

I am working on a beamer presentation where I would like to place a couple of graphs on one slide. The resolution is however not sufficient and I was wondering if it would be possible to enlarge the graphs to the full screen size if pointing with the cursor?

Comment: How about making the smaller graph into a hyperlink that would take you (upon clicking, not hovering over) to another frame containing a higher resolution version of the same graph?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12290/automatic-zoom-in-hypertext-boxes-in-pdf

Answer (score 2):

The following produces five slides: the first contains four images that are scaled down to fit within one frame, and the rest of the four slides each contains a bigger version of the images. By clicking on a smaller image, you can jump to the slide containing the bigger version of that image, and clicking the larger image will take you back to the initial slide of four images.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Cards}\label{cards}
\centering
\hyperlink{img1_alone}{\includegraphics[scale=.25]{img1}}
\hyperlink{img2_alone}{\includegraphics[scale=.25]{img2}}
\hyperlink{img3_alone}{\includegraphics[scale=.25]{img3}}
\hyperlink{img4_alone}{\includegraphics[scale=.25]{img4}}\par
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Jack}\label{img1_alone}
\centering
\hyperlink{cards}{\includegraphics[scale=.7]{img1}}\par
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Queen}\label{img2_alone}
\centering
\hyperlink{cards}{\includegraphics[scale=.7]{img2}}\par
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{King}\label{img3_alone}
\centering
\hyperlink{cards}{\includegraphics[scale=.7]{img3}}\par
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Ace}\label{img4_alone}
\centering
\hyperlink{cards}{\includegraphics[scale=.7]{img4}}\par
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image][image]

Answer (score 1):

There is an example in the [documentation](http://mirrors.dotsrc.org/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf) (chapter 11.3) and a special command `\framezoom` for doing this.

Here is my example:

```
\documentclass[17pt]{beamer}

\begin{document}

% Main part of presentation

\begin{frame}<1>[plain,label=tramwaje]
\framezoom<1><2>[border](0.3cm,2cm)(2cm,2cm)
\only<1>{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=\textheight,keepaspectratio]{stary__}}
\only<2>{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=\textheight,keepaspectratio]{stary__}}
\only<3>{The end}
\end{frame}

%Zoomed part will be omitted in “normal” presentation
%…
%…

\begin{frame}
Thank you for your attention!
\end{frame}

\appendix

\againframe<2>{tramwaje}

\end{document}
```

I have realised, that it stop working as described in the documentation: there is a link, but no return to un-zoomed version…
Source files (tram.tex, stary__.jpg) and resulting (tram.pdf) can be found at the end of the [directory](http://goo.gl/cx0Mm).

Comment: This post would be more appropriate as a comment than as an answer. Perhaps you could improve it by adding an example of how `\framezoom` is used.