# In Beamer: Zoom in on figure when clicked and zoom back out when clicked again

Tags: beamer, graphics, animations

I'm completely new to Beamer and was wondering if there is a way to first show an overview of multiple images in a frame and then discuss each image in more detail by simply clicking on it to fill the screen. Other parts of the frame like the title and a caption don't have to remain visible. I would like this to work in Apple's Preview.

Here's a minimal working example illustrating my layout

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{demo}{graphicx}
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Demo}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth,height=0.35\textheight]{demo1}
\hfil
\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth,height=0.35\textheight]{demo2}
\vspace{9pt}
\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth,height=0.35\textheight]{demo3}
\hfil
\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth,height=0.35\textheight]{demo4}
\captionof{figure}{Nice overview! Let's look get into more detail on each image.}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Try [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12290).

Comment: This seems promising. Unfortunately, I just tested it and it doesn't work in Apple's Preview, which I will be using to show my presentation. I will clarify my question.

Comment: So \framezoom is acceptable?

Comment: As far as I understand, Beamer's `\framezoom` creates a new frame with a larger version of the image whereas I would like to remain on one frame and just instruct the PDF viewer to enlarge the area which shows the image.

Comment: @PacificOrion Yeah, its called `Preview`. What do you expect?

Answer (score 4):

On second thought, specifying clickable areas by absolute coordinates is too much work.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Demo}
\hypertarget{Demo}{}
\centering
\hyperlink{demo1}{%
\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth,height=0.35\textheight]{example-image}}
\hfil
\hyperlink{demo2}{%
\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth,height=0.35\textheight]{example-image-a}}
\vspace{9pt}
\hyperlink{demo3}{%
\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth,height=0.35\textheight]{example-image-b}}
\hfil
\hyperlink{demo4}{%
\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth,height=0.35\textheight]{example-image-c}}
\captionof{figure}{Nice overview!. Let's look get into more detail on each image.}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{demo1}
\hypertarget{demo1}{}
\hyperlink{Demo}{
\hfil\includegraphics[width=.9\textwidth,height=.7\textheight]{example-image}}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{demo2}
\hypertarget{demo2}{}
\hyperlink{Demo}{
\hfil\includegraphics[width=.9\textwidth,height=.7\textheight]{example-image-a}}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{demo3}
\hypertarget{demo3}{}
\hyperlink{Demo}{
\hfil\includegraphics[width=.9\textwidth,height=.7\textheight]{example-image-b}}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{demo4}
\hypertarget{demo4}{}
\hyperlink{Demo}{
\hfil\includegraphics[width=.9\textwidth,height=.7\textheight]{example-image-c}}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That's pretty good. Ideally, zooming in on images wouldn't require jumping to a new slide. Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: @Pacific Orion - Other than the work by AlexG, you might try the tikz spy feature.  One can also use tikz to import graphics directly.

Comment: Interesting but also not quite what I am looking for.

Comment: You do realize that every time you add \pause you are creating a new slide.  You could move these expanded views to an appendix.  You can replace the frame environment with \newpage.  You could create a fake caption to make it look like the original slide.  You could put the expanded views into a different file and link using \href.  But unless PDF supports hidden pages, the expanded views are going to wind up somewhere in the document.

Comment: Well not if a click simply makes the PDF viewer zoom in on the image, which was my initial goal. It was just an interesting idea for my presentation and if it's not possible or too much of a hassle, I don't have to do it...

Comment: As I said, I'm new to `beamer` and have never used `\pause`. Does it stop an automatically progressing slideshow?

Comment: \pause is used for a power point type presentation.  It creates a partial slide up to the \pause, then a second slide up to the next \pause, and so on.