# Zooming on one of multiple images in a slide using Tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, columns

I would like to zoom in on one of the 12 images that I have organized in 3 columns. There are 4 images per column, all the same height and width.

There is one image that I would like to zoom in on and highlight in a circle in the center of the slide.

I have been trying to accomplish this using `tikzpicture` but, as you will be able to see in my `MWE`, the zoom is not being "superimposed" on the slide, but rather interfering with the organization of the other images. Besides that, I am not zooming in on the entire image, but rather on a part of it.

How can I fix my code to arrive at my desired final result?

```
\documentclass[10pt, compress]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{spy}


\begin{frame}

\begin{columns}[t]
\column{.3\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=3cm,height=1.75cm]{img1}\\
\includegraphics[width=3cm,height=1.75cm]{img2}\\
\includegraphics[width=3cm,height=1.75cm]{img3}\\
\includegraphics[width=3cm,height=1.75cm]{img4}
\column{.3\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=3cm,height=1.75cm]{img5}\\
\includegraphics[width=3cm,height=1.75cm]{img6}\\
\includegraphics[width=3cm,height=1.75cm]{img7}\\
\includegraphics[width=3cm,height=1.75cm]{img8}\\
\column{.3\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=3cm,height=1.75cm]{img9}\\
%%% this is the image that I want to zoom in on
\begin{tikzpicture}[
spy using outlines={
  circle,
  magnification=10,
  size=5cm,
  connect spies}]
\node[inner sep=0pt] {\pgfimage[width=3cm,height=1.75cm]{img10}};
\only<2>{\spy[red!70!black] on (0.88,0.15) in node at (.5\textwidth,0);}
\end{tikzpicture}
\includegraphics[width=3cm,height=1.75cm]{img11}\\
\includegraphics[width=3cm,height=1.75cm]{img12}\\

\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

**Basically, my main question is how can I zoom in on ONE entire image of the 12 above?**

Here is what is happening, so far:
[image: Error that the code is making]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Thank you for the tip @HenriMenke I already updated the code in the example.

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12290/automatic-zoom-in-hypertext-boxes-in-pdf

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the `overlay` option to your `tikzpicture`; if additionally you use `remember picture`, now you have access to the `current page` nodes and you can place the spying glass on `current page.center`, for example (this last part is, of course, optional; you can place the magnifying glass anywhere you want on the frame using absolute coordinates too); the important thing is to place the glass in a space that won't be occupied for object added after the glass (otherwise, those objects would overlap the glass).

Here's a little example:

```
\documentclass[10pt, compress]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{spy}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{columns}[t]
\column{.3\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=3cm,height=1.75cm]{example-image-a}\\
  \includegraphics[width=3cm,height=1.75cm]{example-image-a}\\
  \includegraphics[width=3cm,height=1.75cm]{example-image-a}\\
  \includegraphics[width=3cm,height=1.75cm]{example-image-a}
\column{.3\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=3cm,height=1.75cm]{example-image-b}\\
  \includegraphics[width=3cm,height=1.75cm]{example-image-b}\\
  \includegraphics[width=3cm,height=1.75cm]{example-image-b}\\
  \includegraphics[width=3cm,height=1.75cm]{example-image-b}\\
\column{.3\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=3cm,height=1.75cm]{example-image-c}\\
  \parbox[c][1.75cm][c]{3cm}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
      overlay,
      remember picture,
      spy using outlines={%
        circle,
        magnification=10,
        size=5cm,
        connect spies
        }
    ]
    \node[
      inner sep=0pt,
      anchor=west,
      outer sep=0pt
    ] 
    {\pgfimage[width=3cm,height=1.75cm]{example-image-c}};
    \only<2>{%
      \spy[red!70!black] on (1.4,0.15) in node at (current page.center);
    }
    \end{tikzpicture}%
  }\\
  \includegraphics[width=3cm,height=1.75cm]{example-image-c}\\
  \includegraphics[width=3cm,height=1.75cm]{example-image-c}
\end{columns}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

An animation of the output:

[image]

If you want to zoom on the whole image, you can adjust the `magnification`, `width` and `height` keys (`width`=`magnification`x`image width`, `height`=`magnification`x`image height`):

```
\documentclass[10pt, compress]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{spy}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{columns}[t]
\column{.3\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=3cm,height=1.75cm]{example-image-a}\\
  \includegraphics[width=3cm,height=1.75cm]{example-image-a}\\
  \includegraphics[width=3cm,height=1.75cm]{example-image-a}\\
  \includegraphics[width=3cm,height=1.75cm]{example-image-a}
\column{.3\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=3cm,height=1.75cm]{example-image-b}\\
  \includegraphics[width=3cm,height=1.75cm]{example-image-b}\\
  \includegraphics[width=3cm,height=1.75cm]{example-image-b}\\
  \includegraphics[width=3cm,height=1.75cm]{example-image-b}\\
\column{.3\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=3cm,height=1.75cm]{example-image-c}\\
  \parbox[c][1.75cm][c]{3cm}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
      overlay,
      remember picture,
      spy using outlines={%
        magnification=2.5,
        width=7.5cm,
        height=4.375cm,
        connect spies
        }
    ]
    \node[
      inner sep=0pt,
      anchor=west,
      outer sep=0pt
    ] (a)
    {\pgfimage[width=3cm,height=1.75cm]{example-image-c}};
    \only<2>{%
      \spy[red!70!black] on (1.5,0) in node at ([xshift=-2cm]current page.center);
    }
    \end{tikzpicture}%
  }\\
  \includegraphics[width=3cm,height=1.75cm]{example-image-c}\\
  \includegraphics[width=3cm,height=1.75cm]{example-image-c}
\end{columns}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @GonzaloMedina this is a great solution, however, it still does not address the issue of magnifying the entire image. As in your video example, the magnifying class is magnifying a small portion of the image, I would like to magnify the entire image. Is there a way to tweak the coordinates in the code in order to do that?

Comment: @owwoow14 Please see my updated answer. Is it something like that what you had in mind?

Comment: Your updated answer is exactly what I had in mind. Works perfectly, thanks.