# Skipping multiple slides in beamer,back and forth

Tags: beamer

I'm preparing a beamer presentation which includes lengthy formulas and would like to be able to skip back or forth when I want to refer to a formula already stated...how can I achieve this

Comment: You have such capabilities through, for example, `\beamerskipbutton,
\beamergotobutton,
\beamergotobutton`.

Comment: Getting back to where you started is the hard part.  Alternatively you can use the hyperref \href[pdfnewwindow]... then get back by closing the window.

Comment: Also `\againframe` makes a copy of a previous frame.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tooltip that works with all pdf readers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/155518/tooltip-that-works-with-all-pdf-readers)

Comment: Check also `\beamerreturnbutton`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## First Approach

The first step is to set up a hyperlink that brings you to the stated formula. And then...

[image]

[image]

If you want just that two buttons, do the following

```
\documentclass{beamer}
    \hypersetup{colorlinks}
    \usepackage{tikz}

\defbeamertemplate*{navigation symbols}{just back and forward}
{%
  \hbox{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}%
        \path(0pt,0pt)(40pt,20pt);
        \fill[black!20](10pt,3pt)rectangle(35pt,17pt);
        \fill[black!10](10pt,10pt)circle(10pt);
        \draw[<-,line width=3](3pt,10pt)--(17pt,10pt);
        \draw[->,line width=2.5](22pt,10pt)--(33pt,10pt);
    \end{tikzpicture}\kern-40pt%
    \Acrobatmenu{GoBack}{\vbox to20pt{}\kern20pt}%
    \Acrobatmenu{GoForward}{\vbox to20pt{}\kern20pt}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\Huge

\makeatletter
\foreach\i in{1,...,8}{
    \frame{
        \foreach\j in{1,...,8}{
            \ifnum\i=\j
                This is page \i \par
            \else
                \hyperlink{page.\j}{Go to page \j} \par
            \fi
        }
    }
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

## Second Approach (not yet working)

Potentially you can set up a hyperlink button that brings you to the current page but with different zoom.

This means that you can typeset a very tiny formula somewhere at the current page; and then use a button to zoom in. Usually your PDF viewer will provide a shortcut to let you **zoom to fit**; and that is how you go back.

Someone had done this before. But it a little too complex to be explained here. So I will leave the link here: [Automatic "Zoom in" hypertext boxes in PDF](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12290/automatic-zoom-in-hypertext-boxes-in-pdf)
[image]