# Zoom by hovering mouse on a pdf image on beamer

Tags: beamer, pdftex

i found this topic about pop ups of references equations...
[hovering on eqref](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82336/mouseover-events-in-beamer-hovering-on-eqref-and-a-comment-containing-the-orig)

And my question is if can we do something similar on pdf images.

I have some pdf images that when compliled directly look like this:
[image]

and i would like to hover the mouse over and show a zoomed version to show the details...

is this even possible?

Regards,

Comment: You previous questions all have answers which seems to answer the questions. Can you check which ones solve your problems and accept them?

Comment: right!! Done!!!

Comment: Look at this: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/362027

Comment: @LuisGómezGuzmán Does the answer AlexG linked to, solves your problem?

Comment: I'm sorry, i haven't had the time to look into this again. As soon as i do i'll report back.

Comment: The link provided by AlexG is a nice solution. Thankz!!

Answer (score 1):

**Possibility 1:**

Use a pdf viewer with such capabilities. For example the pdf viewer which ships along with `TeXStudio` has a magnifier with adjustable shape, magnification and size:

[image]

**Possibility 2:**

Not with hovering the mouse, but with click and predefined areas: Look into the `\framezoom` command. An example from the beamer user guide (11.3 Adding Anticipated Zooming):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}<1>[label=zooms]
  \frametitle<1>{A Complicated Picture}
  \framezoom<1><2>[border](0cm,0cm)(2cm,1.5cm)
  \framezoom<1><3>[border](1cm,3cm)(2cm,1.5cm)
  \framezoom<1><4>[border](3cm,2cm)(3cm,2cm)
  \pgfimage[height=8cm]{example-image}
\end{frame}
\againframe<2->[plain]{zooms}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanxz, but i already implemented this, and also with spy command from tikz...