# Enlarge pdf-s inserted with pdfpages

Tags: pdf, pdfpages, links

I use `\usepackage{pdfpages}` in the header, and then `includepdf[pages=-, nup = 2x2, linktodoc = true]{mypdf.pdf}`. So, as well as mypdf.pdf is in the same folder, links work very well. But can one omit these inserted documents, so that the click on the small inserted pdf will enlarge it in a new window?

Thank you.

Comment: Take a look at `hyperref`. `pdfpages` is not the right tool for this.

Comment: I am not sure that I got your idea correct. Thank you. @cfr

Comment: Use the `hyperref` package. It does things like this: adding links, for example. If you want a link, that's probably what you need to look at.

Comment: @cfr if you go to eBay and watch some pictures, you can click on them, and they will enlarge. You can do the same with pdfpages, as with "linktodoc=true" your documents will open enlarged in a new window. My question is not about hyperlinks, but about how to make them do the same thing, if the source documents used in `\includepdf` are not present. You can see this as "extract an embedded page into a new window". Hope that it is clear now.

Comment: Well, you would need to insert the enlarged copies of the PDFs to the end of the current PDF again and link from the smaller versions to the larger ones. Alternatively add a link to the same page but with a view area which enlarges the clicked PDF image in the viewer. This is however viewer dependent (might only work with Acrobat Reader for example) and will propably not open it in a new window.

Comment: You may use the [↗`\zoombox{<content>}`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/362027) macro with `\includegraphics[scale=..., page=...]{mypdf}` as the `<content>` argument for generating clickable thumbnails.

Comment: You say 'you can do the same with pdfpages', so what is it you want to do with `pdfpages` which you don't know how to do or can't do with it?