# Possible to make pan and zoom animation?

Tags: animations

Is it possible to make a pan and zoom animation using Latex?

For instance, in the enclosed image, is it possible to zoom on Hello World 1, stay there for a while then move to Hello World 2 maintaining the zoom, stay there for a while, etc.

I am sorry, I am unable to provide any MWE here. But I have attached the animations (first four seconds split into two files).

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Not easily. For non-animated zooming see, e. g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/362027

Comment: Or this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/12293