# How to enlarge an image

Tags: diagrams

Okay so there are so many threads about this such as:
https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/12293
https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/4323
https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/131850

I tried to import them into my latex file. They did not work. So i would like to know how to enlarge an image when I click on it.[image] Also would love a step by step guide or an easy import into my latex document.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: how do i enlarge a image in blender as shown by the gif.

Comment: @A1pha: Blender? Is that your PDF viewer? Note that certain PDF features might be limited to Adobe-specific viewers.

Comment: no it isn't. Why does the PDF viewer matter?

Comment: I just want to know the code that would work for mine @Werner

Comment: @A1pha: If the provided code in the linked answers don't work in *your* PDF viewer, try to see if the same PDF does provide the desired result when viewed through something like Adobe Reader. If that's the case, you'll know that the problem is not with LaTeX, or the PDF specification, but with your viewer (and therefore off topic on this site). Can you try the above suggestion and give us some feedback?